# How do I convert a row of a matrix into a vector?

Tags: matlab

I Have a matrix of 10 rows, each row is a plaintext that I need to encrypt by calling the function encrypt (plaintext, key):

```
Plaintext Matrix:  
  208    15   217   252   128    35    50   252   209   120    97   140   235   220    32   251
       231   174   143    43   125    66    49   143    48   139    81   103   154   229    93   229
        32    10   237    65   224    22    83   238    31    15   252    27   179    48   173   221
       233    18   178   101    90   109   225   184   210   168   183   185   190   169    96   205
       161   133   149    18   115    65   120   123   163   227   105   157    98   240   221   142
        24    24   208   175   246    76   103   163     4    28    25   200    64   249    74   107
        71   209   225   103    10   108    45   227   229   112   188   145     9    27    34    32
       140   209   253   251   249    30   248    50   131    71   163   207   120    45   172   167
       245   184     0   102    48   126   104   101   139   252    18   147   165   191    51   221
       247    38   221   158   170   180   216   253   155   155    30   241    71    12   222    70
```

I just need to convert  each row  in the matrix to a vector.

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: First, I'm not familiar with the `encrypt` function in MATLAB and can't find it in the official documentation. If this is not a built-in function, then I think it unreasonable to think that anyone could guess which implementation you're actually using. Second, the error says that you must use a vector and not a cell array. You are passing the second argument to `encrypt` as a cell array. I would suggest trying it as a normal vector with square brackets `[..]` instead of curly brackets `{..}`.

Comment: I  think that the problem that I don't  know how to convert a matrix row into a vector? I  have always problems with vectors.

Comment: @user6594048 You should then state clearly what the problem is. Try to reduce it as much as possible, and post an example with input and desired output

Comment: @LuisMendo, i edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: So just `v = A(n,:)`? `A` is the matrix, `n` is the row index, `v` is the resulting vector

Comment: Thank you very much it works.

Comment: My function encrypt works too. @LuisMendo Thank you